# transaction get revert by calling view method from another contract constructor

Tags: contract-development

I havae two contract `Record` and `Register`.

`Register.sol` looks like:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Register {
    string private name;

    constructor(string entityname) public {
        name = entityname;
    }

    function getName() public view returns (string username) {
        return name;
    }
}
```

And in `Record.sol`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "./Register.sol";

contract Record {    
    constructor(address ownerAddr, address providerAddr) public {
        Register(ownerAddr).getName();
        Register(providerAddr).getName();
    }
}
```

FYI, `Record` just want to call `getName()` method of Register contract in its constructor. In the test file I want to create new `Record` using the following code but got this error **VM Exception while processing transaction: revert**.

```
beforeEach('create new Register and Record contract', async () => {
    providerA = await Register.new("Dr Strange", {from: accounts[0]});
    providerB = await Register.new("Maybe", {from: accounts[1]});
    record = await Record.new(providerA.address, providerB.addresss);
})
```

What should I do?

- **Truffle v4.1.14 (core: 4.1.14)**
- **Solidity v0.4.24 (solc-js)**
- **Ganache v1.2.2**

**============================ UPDATE ==============================**

I think its the problem of the contract iteself, not the test script. Because using Remix, `Register` contract can be deployed, but `Record` cannot even be deployed.

Comment: Change `returns (string username)` to `returns (string)`.

Comment: Changed to `returns (string)`. Problem exists.

Comment: Also, run `console.log(providerA.address, providerB.addresss)`. Make sure that they are not `undefined`. That would explain the `revert` exception. On web3.js v1 you should use `_address`, not `address` (though Truffle uses web3.js v0 as far as I'm aware of).

Comment: The output is `0x048964912779d7896841ecb0ab2ac2ca8a022d39 0x568d7256e3aa7789bc039f314eeebba7ff3005a9` and they exist in Ganache as **CREATED CONTRACT ADDRESS**.

Comment: So maybe it's the fact that you're creating temporary instances. Try to declare the two instances first, and only then call the `getName` function.

Comment: I think its the problem of the contract iteself, not the test script. Because using Remix, `Register` contract can be deployed, but `Record` cannot even be deployed.

Comment: Take a minute to think what does `Register(ownerAddr)` even mean. The constructor of `Register` takes a string, not an address.

Answer (score 1):

guestA and guestB are not initialized yet. Therefore, their values will be 0. You can't call getName on address 0.

You'll have to initialize these variables with the addresses of the actual deployed Registers.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. But the previous post was misleading. As stated in the updated post, both Register contracts has been initialized in the test script

Answer (score 1):

Take a minute to think what does `Register(ownerAddr)` even mean.

The constructor of `contract Register` takes a `string`, not an `address`.

That said, here is how I would implement this:

File `IRegister.sol`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

interface IRegister {
    function getName() public view returns (string);
}
```

File `Register.sol`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "./IRegister.sol";

contract Register is IRegister {
    string private name;

    constructor(string entityname) public {
        name = entityname;
    }

    function getName() public view returns (string) {
        return name;
    }
}
```

File `Record.sol`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "./IRegister.sol";

contract Record {
    constructor(address ownerAddr, address providerAddr) public {
        IRegister x = IRegister(ownerAddr);
        IRegister y = IRegister(providerAddr);
        string xName = x.getName();
        string yName = y.getName();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, problem solved. But someone please tell me why.

The problem is solved by seperating the record contract initializer to `it` part, namely from

```
beforeEach('create new Register and Record contract', async () => {
    providerA = await Register.new("Dr Strange", {from: accounts[0]});
    providerB = await Register.new("Maybe", {from: accounts[1]});
    record = await Record.new(providerA.address, providerB.addresss);
})
```

to

```
beforeEach('create new Register and Record contract', async () => {
    providerA = await Register.new("Dr Strange", {from: accounts[0]});
    providerB = await Register.new("Maybe", {from: accounts[1]});
})

it("check record initializer", async () => {
    record = await Record.new(providerA.address, providerB.address, "Test");
    record.owner().then(patient => {
        assert.equal(patient, accounts[1], "Owner of the record is wrong!");
    })
})
```